# I2Cの初歩的な質問です

Tags: windows, c, i2c

とあるデバイスの LED を変更するプログラムを書こうとしています。

I2C アドレス: 0x93

Read Data Format:
Send 0xA0 ' Read 32 Byte Array[byArray[32]]
byArray[0]'LED Mode[Mode0'Mode1'Mode2'Mode3'Mode4]
byArray[1]'Red
byArray[2]'Green
byArray[3]'Blue
byArray[12]'LED'on/off

Write Data Format:
8 Byte Data[byData[8]]
Default'Switch'LED mode'Red'Green'Blue'Default'Default
Example: 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04 (=Mode0 Red)

1stbyte header: 0xA0
2ndbyte: Switch(0x00 = LED MODE, 0xFC = ON/OFF MODE)
3rdbyte: If 2nd byte = 0x00, select LED MODE[MODE0(0x00)'MODE1(0x01)'MODE2(0x02)'MODE3(0x03)'MODE4(0x04)]
Else if 2nd byte = 0xFC, select ON/OFF(0x01 ON/0x00 OFF)\
4th-6th: RGB value
7th-8th: reserved, keep 0x00 and 0x04

与えられた情報はこれだけですがこれだけでプログラムを書けるものでしょうか？
やりたいことは、Windows で C言語でデバイスの LED(光り方) を変更することです。
これでプログラムが書けるのであればサンプルコードを教えていただけないでしょうか？
デバイスは、PCI Express 上にあります。
VisualStudio の使い方と C/C++ の知識はあります。

Comment: どのような機器構成になっているのでしょうか？

「デバイスは、PCI Express 上にあります」という事ですから、デバイスはWindowsのPCに差し込まれているドーターボードのような感じを受けます。

その一方で「I2C アドレス: 0x93」と書かれていますから、デバイスはI2Cバスに接続されているようにも感じます。

デバイスが何なのか、PCとデバイス（他の装置があれば、それも）がどのように接続されているのか等の詳細情報を質問に追加すべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: デバイスがユーザのプログラムを受け付ける想定で開発されていれば、デバイスの開発元からSDKなりライブラリなりが配布(もしくは販売)されいてると思います。それらを入手してみてはどうでしょうか。現状の情報だけでは難しいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

通常の Windows アプリケーションから直接ハードウエアデバイスをアクセスする手段はありません。通常は「デバイスドライバ」なるものが仲介してくれます。デバイスマネージャで表示されるアレですね。

Windows アプリケーションが Read や Write や IOCTL という形でデバイスドライバをアクセスすると、デバイスドライバがハードウエアデバイスにコマンドを発行するという形をとることになるでしょう。この場合 I2C がどうこうといった話はデバイスドライバが中で吸収してくれるのでアプリケーションプログラマはその辺を知っておく必要はありません。が、ドライバにどうアクセスするとよいのかの情報が必要です。

あるいは今要求されているのはデバイスドライバを書くこと、なんでしょうか？それであれば難度が上がります。こういう場で説明できるとは思えません。こっちなら I2C の信号をどう生成するかの情報が必要です。

まずはもっと詳しい資料の入手を試みましょう。作れと要求されているのがデバイスドライバなのかアプリケーションなのか、あたりも要確認です。今提示されたその説明だけでは何もできない、ってことで。

Answer (score 0):

普通のインテルPCと普通のWindows(Home/Pro)では出来ないようです。  
Windows 10 IoT Core または Windows Enterprise が必要と出ています。

[GPIO、I2C、SPI へのユーザー モード アクセスの有効化](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enable-usermode-access)

> Windows 10 IoT Core と Windows Enterprise で使用可能な RhProxy
>   という新しいドライバーが、GpioClx リソースと SpbCx リソースをユーザーモードに公開します。

[Windows 10 IoT Core で I2C](https://koudenpa.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/05/16/060659)  
[Windows 10 IoT CoreでI2Cを使う](http://todotani.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2015/12/windows-10-io-1.html)

まあ、Windows Driver Kitでデバイスドライバを作成できる人ならばできるかもしれませんが。  
他に参考になりそうな情報を示します。

[Intel Z370 - SMBus on PCIe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50236420/9014308)  
[Industrial PC Requirements to Access GPIO/I2C/SPI ... - Annabooks](http://www.annabooks.com/Articles/Articles_IoT10Core/Windows-10-IoT-microIO-Requirements-on-IA-Rev1.6.pdf)  
[Windows 10 IoT Enterprise](https://sec.ch9.ms/sessions/winhec/slides/04-2015ShenzhenWinHECFallWorkshopKeynote-CreateyourIndustrydevicewithWindows10IoT.pdf)  
[PCI Express - PALTEK](https://www.paltek.co.jp/mail/pciexpress/2006/04/04_PCIe_kentou.pdf)  
[PALTEKボードソリューション](https://www.paltek.co.jp/board/index.htm)